# El Capitan drops USB-connected speakers

Tags: audio, usb, macos, speakers

I've been running the Beta for El Capitan for a while now, but since the OS got officially released today, I feel it's okay to ask a question.

> FYI: I'm running the GM.

I have an iMac with a Bose Companion 5 connected through USB. It's recognised perfectly fine, but once in a while, it just seems to stop sending audio over USB and just starts playing on the internal speakers.

This never really happens in the middle of a song or video, it seems to happen between songs/videos, when the iMac doesn't output sound for a while. This can sometimes mean that one Youtube-video plays over the USB-speakers, while the next, which gets started 2 seconds after the previous one, plays over the internal speakers.

OSX still recognises the speakers (shows them in `system settings` under `sound`) when it stops sending audio, but it simply won't play. When it suddenly starts playing on the internal speakers, changing volume doesn't work, because the USB-speakers are still selected in system settings. I have to change to `Internal Speakers` before I can change the volume. If I then wait a little bit and change back to `Bose USB Audio`, the external speakers work without trouble, until it decides to do the above all over again.

Anyone has a fix for this problem? I have of course reported it to Apple while testing the beta, but I guess they haven't picked it up.

Comment: I have the same issue and can confirm the behaviour you have described. Unplugging the USB Speaker does not help. Switching to internal speakers PLUS stopping/starting sound (i.e. track played in iTunes) makes internal speakers work (so not a problem with the source), but switching back is not always possible.

Comment: Same issue here. NuForce USB uDac2.

Comment: How is this still a problem... Jeez...